# Batch file problems with IF statements and parantheses

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to batch start some experiments.
I need to redo some of them but not all.
The ones where (s==1000 and r==0.5 and (c==1 or c==25 or c==75)) have been done ok so can be skipped (they take a long time to run).
Ever since I introduced the IF statements, the way the parentheses are parsed is giving errors. I keep getting unexpected ( or ).
I've tried rewriting the whole thing, but to no avail.

I know this is a lot like a 'please check my code for bugs' question, but I am really at my wits end here.

```
SET dotest=1
FOR %%s IN (1000,2000) do (
    FOR %%r IN (0.5,0.75,1) do (
        FOR %%c IN (1,25,75,100) do (
            IF (%%s==1000) (
                IF (%%r==0.5) (
                    IF (%%c==1)
                        (SET dotest==0)
                    IF (%%c==25)
                        (SET dotest==0)
                    IF (%%c==75)
                        (SET dotest==0)
                )
            )
            IF (%%dotest==1) (
                ECHO "Hello World!"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: First you should read the HELP for the correct syntax, type `IF /?` at the console. Also `cmd /?` as you have more syntax errors than code

Comment: you'll need delayed expansion as the `dotest` changes its value within brackets.

Comment: `set` uses one equal sign only.

Comment: Wow sorry about that one haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%s IN (1000,2000) do (
    FOR %%r IN (0.5,0.75,1) do (
        FOR %%c IN (1,25,75,100) do (
            SET dotest=1
            IF %%s == 1000 (
                IF %%r == 0.5  (
                    IF %%c == 1 (
                       SET dotest=0
                    )
                    IF %%c==25 (
                        SET dotest=0
                    )
                    IF %%c==75 (
                        SET dotest=0
                    )
                )
            )
            IF !dotest! == 1 (
                ECHO "Hello World^!" %%s,%%r,%%c
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You should be able to run this without syntax errors - but there's no way for me to know if the logic is correct.The issues with your example:

1. `IF` conditions are defined without brackets
2. Start the brackets context after the if on the same line
3. If you change the dotest value within brackets and need it again in this brackets content you'll need delayed expansion and `!` instead of `%`
4. In a `SET` command use only one equal sign

Comment: And a counting FOR loop need a parameter `/L` and can only count integers not fractions. You forget the `setlocal Enabel...`

Comment: @jeb - thanks. I'm not sure about `FOR /L`  - the OP might need an iteration.Anyway here are used double numbers which will not work.

Comment: @jeb: That's ok. Try `FOR %r IN (0.5,0.75,1) do @echo %r`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I think this is the best answer so far.
The only thing is that it does not execute the echo Hello World statement now. I'll have to look into the logic, but if you can see why, please comment.

Comment: I moved the `set dotest=1` but if it works as expected depends on your expectations

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of IF is `IF x==y (...)` and not `IF (x==y) (...)`. No () around the condition! Further you will have to add `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script and address to dotest as `!dotest!` instead of `%dotest%`.

Comment: tx, I was actually just trying stuff because of the parentheses error

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try

```dos
     for %%s in ( 1000, 2000
) do for %%r in ( 0.5,  0.75,  1
) do for %%c in ( 1, 25, 75, 100
) do (
    set "doTest=1"
    if %%s==1000 if %%r==0.5 if not %%c==100 set "doTest="
    if defined doTest (
        echo "Hello World!"
    )
)
```

All the unneeded parenthesis and checks removed from code, while keeping the logic exposed both in question and original code.

In this case, as the variable is only used as a switch, instead of testing the value inside (that could need delayed expansion), if it tested if the variable is defined (has value) or undefined (has no value)

*edit* for a more usual code format

```dos
for %%s in (1000, 2000) do for %%r in (0.5, 0.75, 1) do for %%c in (1, 25, 75, 100) do (
    set "doTest=1"
    IF %%s==1000 if %%r=0.5 if not %%c==100 set "doTest="
    IF defined doTest (
        echo "Hello World!"
    )
)
```

Comment: Short and works (probably as expected), but the format is a bit nasty

Comment: @jeb, It  is unusual, but for nested `for` commands where all the code is placed in the inner one i find this easier to read and follow the logic, at least in posted code. But I have to admit i don't use it a lot in real code.